# sed command is failing, how to fix that?

Tags: linux, sed, line, github-actions

I have a github actions workflow, to send emails at the end of build, I have created a html file and kept place holders there.
At the pipeline, I am running sed commands to replace the place holders with the github variables.

```
- name: Update HTML file values
  shell: cmd
  run: |
    set html=".\\installs_repo\\Projectwise ISM files\\${{ env.Version }}\\mart_installs_email.html"
    copy /Y ".\\installs_repo\\Projectwise ISM files\\${{ env.Version }}\\mart_installs_email.template" %html%
    sed -i "s|VAR_WORKFLOW|${{ github.workflow }}|g" %html%
    sed -i "s|VAR_REPO|${{ github.repository }}|g" %html%
    sed -i "s|VAR_RUNNER|${{ github.run_number }}|g" %html%
    sed -i "s|VAR_REF|${{ github.ref_name }}|g" %html%
    sed -i "s|VAR_COMMIT|${{ github.event.head_commit.message }}|g" %html%
    sed -i "s|VAR_COUNT|${{ env.git_commit_count }}|g" %html%
    sed -i "s|VAR_URL|${{ secrets.DAILY_BUILDS_URL }}|g" %html%
    sed -i "s|VAR_VERSION|${{ env.Version }}|g" %html%
```

But whenever there are spaces or new lines or special characters like * in the variable value, especially commit message (VAR_COMMIT is place holder), the pipeline is failing.

If there is space or new line before the commit message.

[image: with space]

If there are multiple lines and stars(*) also.

[image: with lines and stars]

My html file is below with var_ is for place holders.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>VAR_WORKFLOW - Successful</h2>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>GitHub Repository</td>
    <td>VAR_REPO</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Version</td>
    <td>VAR_VERSION</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Github Actions Build Number</td>
    <td>VAR_RUNNER</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>GitHub Branch Name</td>
    <td>VAR_REF</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Commit Message</td>
    <td>**VAR_COMMIT**</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Commit Count or Build Number</td>
    <td>VAR_COUNT</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Daily Builds</td>
    <td><a href="VAR_URL">OneDrive Link</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please create a minimal reproducer. Don't just copy everything. Also, for future people with the same problem, please copy&paste error messages such that they can be searched by.

Comment: I highlighted the code snippet also right and also in the description mentioned which variable is causing the issue. Nothing is unnecessary above

Comment: Nothing is unnecessary for your script, but we would like to see what is needed for reproducing the problem. First show the desired replacement with `commitmsg='normalstring'` and `echo "Replace VAR_COMMIT in this string" | sed "s|VAR_COMMIT|${commitmsg}|"`. Next show a commitmsg with newlines, like `commitmsg=$(printf 'Line %s\n' {1..4})`. Now `sed` returns `sed: -e expression #1, char 19: unterminated `s' command`.